# pydrive redirect_uri_mismatch python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm working on a server using ssh connection in terminal.
I want to load some files to my google drive account.
I set up all the code in python:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

upload_file_list = ['app.py']
for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '1WhLxjusww5Y0IZSXXQz-G3UfwU2Lbdyd'}]})
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.
```

i got also the client_secrets.json and settings.yml anyway this error haunts me.

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

i check multiple time my google console and the uris are respectively:

> authorized javaScript origins: http://localhost:8080

> authorized redirect URIs: http://localhost:8080/

Can someone help me to clarify this problem? thanks

Comment: you should be using an installed / desktop app credentials if this is being run on a server.  It only needs to be a web app if your hosting it on a web server

Comment: My file python run on my university server and i access to it via ssh in terminal. when i run the file it load in my local browser a web page with error: redirect_uri_mismatch. I'm struggling because it's correct for me set up as uris http://localhost:8080 due to the fact that the script is running on the server.

Comment: whats the full error for the redirect uri miss match? there should be a uri there add that.

Comment: Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch 
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: remember it needs to match exactly so  "http ://localhost:8080/" is not the same as " http ://localhost:8080/" nor is https

Comment: i switch my ID client OAuth 2.0 to Desktop type and now it loads a google page, when i continue with my google account the page tell me that it cannot be able to establish a connection with the server localhost:8080.....with this command gauth.CommandLineAuth() it works but i'm abliged each time to paste a verification code in terminal

Comment: Unless you store the authorization your going to have to pass the authorization each time.

Comment: how can i store the authorization?